# Password request from jupyter notebook session even though I don't set it

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook

I can paste URL into my chrome and open Jupyter Notebook without entering password yesterday. But today, when I do the same thing, it request a password or token. I paste the token in the URL, but it doesn't work. However, I have never set a password before and I don't have a file called "jupyter_notebook_config.py".

```
[I 09:46:55.389 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: 
http://localhost:8888/?token=3633a96ee756c4893d2435134b03750f9ab45ae2c0a5f9e2
[I 09:46:55.389 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 09:46:55.389 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 09:46:55.389 NotebookApp] 

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=3633a96ee756c4893d2435134b03750f9ab45ae2c0a5f9e2
```

Could you please give me a help? Thank you.

Comment: Copy the token 3633a96ee756c4893d2435134b03750f9ab45ae2c0a5f9e2 and paste it

Comment: I tried this, but it no luck

Comment: No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser. Set chrome as your default browser

Comment: This is another question I want to ask. The jupyter I use is in remote server. How can I set chrome as my default browser so it can automatically open the browser? I am new to linux. Thank you.

Comment: i know firefox can work but not jupyter

Comment: what do you mean by "but not jupyter" ? do you know how to do so as to make jupyter open in browser automatically after typing the command "jupyter notebook"?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic. Try http://superuser.com .  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.